# Hot to get populated markers from an array in appery IONIC5 application

Tags: google-maps, ionic5, appery.io

I need to populate markers on the map based on a database items. So, an amount of these items can be different.

In a map component i can add markers manually, but i need it to be dynamically.
[How can i add markers manally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O59r.png)

I know how to control 1 marker (lat, lng, other parameters), so i can add xx markers(manually) and then populate them with data from database. But, i know this way is to nowhere, becuase need to hide extra and what to do if need to add more then xx.

Any help is very appritiated.

Answer (score 2):

1 Add a variable "markers" with default value empty array [].
[How to do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvODy.png)

2 Add a variable "map_center" with default value {"lat": 40, "lng": 40}.

3 Activate a map and set a "View point" for it as "map_center.lat" and "map_center.lng" accordingly.
[How to do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkeHf.png)

4 Activate a marker and set for it:

- attribute "*ngFor" with value "let marker of markers".
- attribute "Latitude" with value "marker.lat".
- attribute "Longitude" with value "marker.lng".
  [How to do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsONX.png)

5 On a button click use a following TS code:
[How to do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6oYI.png)

```html
//This is, actually, creates new markers on a map.
this.markers = [{"lat": 51.509865, "lng": -0.118092, "name": "London"}, {"lat": 51.481583, "lng": -3.179090, "name": "Wales"}, {"lat": 51.454514, "lng": -2.587910, "name": "Bristol"}];

//This is to change map center.
this.map_center = {"lat": 51.509865, "lng": -0.118092};
```